# Automorphisms of elliptic curves with a point of order N

Tags: elliptic-curves, modular-forms, moduli-space

Probably a stupid question, but I'm trying to figure out the following:
Suppose we have an element of $X_1(N)$, i.e. an elliptic curve $E$ with a point $p$ of order $N$. If we have another such curve $(E',p')$, then we say that they are isomorphic if there is an isomorphism of elliptic curves $\phi$ such that $\phi(E) = E'$ and $\phi(p) = p'$. Is it correct that an automorphism of these curves is an automorphism $\phi$ of $E$ such that $\phi(p) = p$? Or can we have $\phi(p)$ different from $p$. What worries me is that in the first definition it appears as if the curves don't have any automorphisms at all. Is this correct?

Comment: It's best to distinguish between automorphisms of $E$, and automorphisms of the \emph{pair} $(E, p)$. Most pairs $(E, p)$ don't have any non-trivial automorphisms, i.e. there is no non-identity automorphism of $E$ sending $p$ to $p$. In fact, if $N \ge 4$ then all pairs $(E, p)$ have this property. This is a very good thing, because it is the reason why the moduli problem associated to $X_1(N)$ is representable.